# Send message to Service Bus Queue via REST and receive message via TCP?

Tags: queue, servicebus, azureservicebus

I have a Azure Service Bus queue. I am wanting to use the REST API to post a message to the queue but use an IIS hosted, WCF service using netMessagingBinding to receive the message.

Does anyone have a link to a resource that demonstrates this? Or is anyone able to provide a code sample of how to push a message to a queue using REST POST and then receive using netMessagingBinding?

I believe it is possible after reading this:

> You can send and receive messages to or from the service using REST or .NET managed API, mixing and matching clients using different protocols in a given scenario. For example, you can send a message to a queue using one protocol and consume it using a different protocol.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780717.aspx

I am able to push a message to the queue using netMessagingBinding and receive using netMessagingBinding. I am also able to push a message to the queue using a REST POST and then receive and delete from the queue using a REST DELETE. I just can't REST POST a message and receive with netMessagingBinding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetMessagingBinding always builds a channel stack with BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement+NetMessagingTransportBindingElement.  If the BrokeredMessages in your ServiceBus Queue/Subscription are plain old [text] xml, then BinaryMessageEncoding won’t work, using WCF you’d have use a CustomBinding with TextMessageEncoder and NetMessagingTransportBindingElement instead.

In short you’d need to use a CustomBinding with TextMessageEncodingBindingElement (with MessageVersion = None) and a NetMessagingTransportBindingElement, make sure Action=”*”, and set AddressFilterMode=Any on your ServiceBehavior.

Here are two ways to read a plain old XML message using NetMessagingTransportBindingElement:

Solution #1
Use System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message in the ServiceContract and call Message.GetBody()

```
namespace MessagingConsole
{
    static class Constants {
        public const string ContractNamespace = "http://contoso";
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ContractNamespace)]
    class Record
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITestContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action="*")]
        void UpdateRecord(Message message);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(
        AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)] // This is another way to avoid “The message with To ” cannot be processed at the receiver…”
    class TestService : ITestContract
    {
        [OperationBehavior]
        public void UpdateRecord(Message message)
        {
            Record r = message.GetBody<Record>();
            Console.WriteLine("UpdateRecord called! " + r.Id);
        }
    }

    class ServiceProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solution = "sb://SOMENS";
            string owner = "owner";
            string key = "XXXXXX=";
            string topicPath = "Topic2";
            string subscriptionName = "Sub0";
            TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(owner, key);

            MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.Create(solution, tokenProvider);
            TopicClient sender = factory.CreateTopicClient(topicPath);
            SubscriptionClient receiver = factory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicPath, subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

            string interopPayload = "<Record xmlns='" + Constants.ContractNamespace + "'><Id>4</Id></Record>";
            BrokeredMessage interopMessage = new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(interopPayload)), true);
            sender.Send(interopMessage);

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
                new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.None },
                new NetMessagingTransportBindingElement());
            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri(solution));
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestContract), binding, topicPath + "/Subscriptions/" + subscriptionName);
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(tokenProvider));
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
            Console.ReadLine();            
        }
    }
}
```

Solution #2
Define a MessageContract data type to make the expected Soap contract match what the interop client is sending:

```
namespace MessagingConsole
{
    static class Constants
    {
        public const string ContractNamespace = "http://contoso";
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ContractNamespace)]
    class Record
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
    class RecordMessageContract
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = Constants.ContractNamespace)]
        public Record Record { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITestContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action="*")]
        void UpdateRecord(RecordMessageContract recordMessageContract);
    }

    class ServiceProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solution = "sb://SOMENS";
            string owner = "owner";
            string key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";
            string topicPath = "Topic2";
            string subscriptionName = "Sub0";
            TokenProvider tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(owner, key);

            MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.Create(solution, tokenProvider);
            TopicClient sender = factory.CreateTopicClient(topicPath);
            SubscriptionClient receiver = factory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicPath, subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

            string interopPayload = "<Record xmlns='" + Constants.ContractNamespace + "'><Id>5</Id></Record>";
            BrokeredMessage interopMessage = new BrokeredMessage(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(interopPayload)), true);
            sender.Send(interopMessage);

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
                new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.None },
                new NetMessagingTransportBindingElement());
            ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri(solution));
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestContract), binding, topicPath + "/Subscriptions/" + subscriptionName);
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(tokenProvider));
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(
        AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any
        )]
    class TestService : ITestContract
    {
        [OperationBehavior]
        public void UpdateRecord(RecordMessageContract recordMessageContract)
        {
            Record r = recordMessageContract.Record;
            Console.WriteLine("UpdateRecord called! " + r.Id);
        }
    }
}
```